# Sub select queries for the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a table used to log calls from users:

```
users:
- Id   INT 11
- Name VARCHAR 30

calls:
- Id      INT 11
- UserId  INT 11
- DateBgn DATETIME
- DateEnd DATETIME
- Number  VARCHAR 30
- Type    TYNYINT 1

Type: 1-Incoming call / 2-Outgoing call
```

My knowledge in SQL is very limited, but I was asked to create a query to list the 10 most used phones and get their duration (in seconds) separated by type (OMG!). Something like this:

```
Phone      Type1  Type2
000-0000   350    210
111-1111   300    150
222-2222   300    140
333-3333   230    200
```

Already could get call duration in seconds:

```
TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(DateEnd, DateBgn))
```

And here is what I got so far:

```
SELECT
    Number,
    SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(DateEnd, DateBgn))) AS Duration
FROM
    calls
WHERE
    UserId = 10 AND
    Type = 1            # Incomming Call
GROUP BY
    Number
ORDER BY
    2 DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

This SQL above list for me the top 10 most used phone numbers, but only incoming calls (type = 1). Please, how can I list both separated types?

Thank you!

---

EDIT:

I created a SQL Fiddle for better understanding and tests:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aaf9b4/1

Comment: What does "most used" mean?

Comment: @juergend, sorry, english is not my native language. By "most used" I mean with higher TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(calls.End, calls.Start)). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation

```
SELECT
    Phone,
    SUM(case when Type = 1 then TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(End, Start)) else 0 end) AS Duration1,
    SUM(case when Type = 2 then TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(End, Start)) else 0 end) AS Duration2
FROM
    calls
WHERE
    UserId = 10        
GROUP BY
    Phone
ORDER BY
    SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(End, Start))) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Thank you again! I will try and let you know!

Comment: Sorry about delay, I created I SQL Fiddle for better understand. Please, have a look http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aaf9b4/1

Comment: And the result is not OK because?

Comment: I was making a mistake about results... It's perfect! Thank you!